# Images disappearing when served over https

Tags: image, http, https, cloudflare

I just signed up for a cloudflare account and began forcing everything to https just to see how it worked, and to my surprise, all my images refused to work over https. now this is something I don't understand because the assets are all linked via:

```
HTML:
<img src="./images/image.jpg" />

CSS:
background-image: url(../images/image.jpg);
```

So I figured, I would change it up to use absolute urls with `//` instead of relative paths:

```
HTML:
<img src="//example.com/images/image.jpg" />

CSS:
background-image: url(//example.com/images/image.jpg);
```

this did not work either. so I decided to hard link to https:

```
HTML:
<img src="https://example.com/images/image.jpg" />

CSS:
background-image: url(https://example.com/images/image.jpg);
```

and again, not working. what happens is the images all buffer and as soon as they are fully downloaded and displayed,they disappear abruptly.

All of the images are available over https or http so I do not understand the issue here. Would appreciate a little insight into this and whether its a cloudflare specific issue or an issue with how I'm writing my code. Can anyone confirm that relative paths should call assets via whatever protocol is currently in use? ive not seen any issue with it in the past.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this was a Cloud Flare issue. They have a feature called Rocket Loader, which compresses all your js files into one long minified JS file which was apparently causing one of my scripts to break, only when served over https. It has been raised as a bug with Cloud Flare support (as it is odd that it works over http but not https). This particular issue was with sss.js (Super Simple Slider) the solution supplied by Cloud Flare Support was to change my script tag for sss.js from:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sss.js"></script>
```

and adding **data-cfasync="false"** to the tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false" src="js/sss.js"></script>
```

Apparently this extra bit of code makes Cloud Flare's Auto-Minifier and Rocket Loader ignore that particular file.

Answer (score 1):

Odd problem.

> Would appreciate a little insight into this and whether its a
>   cloudflare specific issue

In general, there should be no problem to do what you are asking, there's no CloudFlare issue

> or an issue with how I'm writing my code.

Both of your code examples look good to me, the first perhaps preferable because it will work with both HTTP and HTTPS

```
<img src="//example.com/images/image.jpg" />
```

Have you

- ruled out browser issues by testing with another browser?
- cleared the CF cache?
- tested with CF set to development mode?
- ruled out any app related issues by testing https image loading on a plain HTML page?
- tried changing the CF SSL Level (Flexible, Full, Strict)?
- if still no joy, can you post a URL?

Good luck!

Comment: Cleared out cache. have no t tested development mode but will do that now, good idea. have tested https over http and the images load up no problem. I have to use flexible because i dont have a cert for the server, its just a plain old website, no logins or anythign that would need to be secure, was just testing the feature out. and sure, the url is https://cgentertainment.com/echo/

Comment: update: development mode seemed to make no difference

Comment: also ive always used relative URLs ex: `src="./images/image.jpg"` as opposed to absolute urls like `src="//example.com/images.image.jpg"` would this not be the best approac since to my knowleds its protocol and domain/directory independent?

Comment: > also ive always used relative URLs ...,  my bad. Relative urls should be fine when referring to assets on your own domain,  though src="//example.com/images.image.jpg" is best for external asests

Comment: I'm seeing a 404 for https://cgentertainment.com/echo/css/images/arr.png, try fixing this and see if it helps.

Comment: that image is referenced by a piece of js and has nothign to do with this issue. i just cant find where its referenced in the js file to remove it. sss.js automatically spawns slider controls for the images, i just have them disabled so it isnt an issue

Comment: just uploaded atransparent png with this filename there in the interest of making sure this is truly not the issue, no change

Comment: as it turns out it was a cloudflare issue. Using Rocket Loader (which puts all your js into one minified request instead of multiple documents) was clearly causing some issue somewhere. now that that has been switched off the issue seems to be gone.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and checking again. I have your HTTPS page working on OSX Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Comment: yes i have it fixed now. as i said ir was Rocket loader. as soon as that was turned off all worked well again

Comment: Hey @JLGriffin , it's not immediately clear to me why Rocket Loader worked on HTTP but not on HTTPS after both clearing the CF cache and setting CF to development mode. For sure I could be missing something, but have you triple-checked that it was indeed caused by Rocket Loader. Remember to clear both your server cache and the CF cache when testing.  Rocket Loader usually gives a good performance boost when it works, so it would be a shame if you've disabled it when it might indeed work for you.

Comment: yes i have. everything cleared. even cloud flare's support on the open ticket seemed to be indicating there was an issue with the way it was parsing jquery via https and they have raised that as a bug report for rocket loader. apparently rocket loader is a beta feature and is still rather buggy its unclear why this was happening. i will reply back if/when i hear back from cloud flare support on this issue. my page load times did drop once rocket loader was turned off, which is rather unfortunate, and id love to be able to use this feature in the future.